# Exporting Contours to DWG with Elevation Data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, contour

I do not have the 3D Analyst extension. I called one of my old professors and he told me to use features to 3D tool and then convert it to a point file. I need to export the contours to a CAD file that contains the elevation data.

I need a work around that does not require the 3D analyst extension, and also is there any reason why my professor said to convert it to a point file?

They are asking me for contours not points.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a homework question.. but I think you will need 3D Analyst for the _Feature to 3D_ tool.

Comment: its for work. I don't have 3D analyst. as previously stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To export contour data from ArcGIS to CAD with 3D elevation you need to do the following process:

1. Define a new field with a name "elevation" in the original shapefile,
2. Then, open the attribute table of the shapefile, copy the values of the "contour"
   field (or whatever the field name the holds the elevation data) into the "elevation" field,
3. Finally, export the contour shapefile to CAD format.

CAD file does not have attribute table, but when you open the CAD file, you will notice that the elevation data in attribute of the shapefile were transferred to the CAD file as 3D. In the CAD software change the view direction from top to right, or any other side view to see the heights.

Comment: Does the field need to be a particular type?

Comment: @CSparks It should be a numerical type like short integer.